# No screen on boot, server is very noisy

Tags: hardware, monitors

I am able to use an outdated server from my work to do some testing at home as I'm pretty new to the hardware part. When booting the server remains very noisy, even after 15 mins. I'm also unable to have any output on my monitor.
The server is a basic superserver 6015B-3.
Anyone who can point out in what direction I should search and what the best options are to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a 1U server. It's always going to be noisy.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there may be an issue on the motherboard.
When fans stay up on full speed (and you didn't configure it explicitly to be so) the boot process doesn't complete.

As your hardware is supermicro, you can try to recover / flash the bios via super.rom and see if this solves the issue.
See [here](http://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=20698) for instructions on the supermicro FAQ.